# Android problems with Viewport

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

When i run the game in Desktop works fine, but when i run it in my android device, the image looks cuted in a half and when i use the PLAY button the game closes, anyone can help me? thank you.

```
public class GameScreen extends AbstractScreen {

    private Viewport viewport;
    private Camera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private float escala;
    private Paddle Lpaddle, Rpaddle;
    private Ball ball;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private int puntuacion, puntuacionMaxima;
    private Preferences preferencias;
    private Music music;
    private Sound sonidoex;

    public GameScreen(Main main) {
        super(main);
            preferencias = Gdx.app.getPreferences("PuntuacionAppPoints");   
            puntuacionMaxima = preferencias.getInteger("puntuacionMaxima");
            music =Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("bgmusic.mp3"));
            music.play();
            music.setVolume((float) 0.3);
            music.setLooping(true);
            sonidoex = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("explosion5.wav"));
    }

    public void create(){
         camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
            viewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, camera);   

    }


    public void show(){
        batch = main.getBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spacebg.png"));
        Texture texturaBola = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bola.png"));
        ball = new Ball(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - texturaBola.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - texturaBola.getHeight() / 2);
        Texture texturaPala= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pala.png"));
        Lpaddle = new LeftPaddle(80, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 -texturaPala.getHeight() /2);
        Rpaddle = new RightPaddle(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() -100, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - texturaPala.getHeight() /2, ball);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        font.setScale(1f);
        puntuacion = 0;


    }

    public void render(float delta){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        updatePuntuacion();
        Lpaddle.update();
        Rpaddle.update();
        ball.update(Lpaddle, Rpaddle);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0,texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
        ball.draw(batch);
        Lpaddle.draw(batch);
        Rpaddle.draw(batch);
        font.draw(batch, "Points: " + Integer.toString(puntuacion), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 5);
        font.draw(batch, "High score: " + Integer.toString(puntuacionMaxima),Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 5);
        batch.end();
    }

    private void updatePuntuacion(){
        if(ball.getBordes().overlaps(Lpaddle.getBordes())) { 
            puntuacion = puntuacion + 1;
            if(puntuacion > puntuacionMaxima)
            puntuacionMaxima = puntuacion;

        }
        if(ball.getBordes().x <= 0) 
            sonidoex.play();

        if(ball.getBordes().x <= 0)
        puntuacion =0;

        if(ball.getBordes().x <=0)
            Gdx.input.vibrate(1000);

        if(ball.getBordes().x <=0)
            Screens.juego.setScreen(Screens.MAINSCREEN);

        ball.comprobarPosicionBola();
        }


    public void hide(){
        font.dispose();
        texture.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        preferencias.putInteger("puntuacionMaxima", puntuacionMaxima);
        preferencias.flush();
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height){      
        float widthImage = texture.getWidth();
        float heightImage = texture.getHeight();
        float r = heightImage / widthImage;
        if(heightImage > height) { 
            heightImage = height;
            widthImage = heightImage / r;
        }
        if(widthImage > width) { 
            widthImage = width;
            heightImage = widthImage * r;
        }
        escala = width / widthImage; 

        if(Gdx.app.getType()== ApplicationType.Android)
        viewport.update(width, height);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use an orthograpic camera.

```
camera=new OrthographicCamera(800,480);
camera.position.set(800/2f,480/2f,0);
viewport=new FitViewport(800,480,camera);
```

Now 0,0 is in the left bottom corner of your screen.

And before doing batch.begin don't forget to set your projection matrix

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
////
////
batch.end();
```